# My python multiplication table syntax does not work as desired

Tags: python-3.x

Coding is not my greatest strength  but so far the python course I am retaking is totally kicking my butt once again . If anybody can give me a hint or help me fix the syntax I would greatly appreciate it.

The following is what should print:

```
What size multiplication table would you like?   (2 - 10): 1
Invalid entry - Enter a number between 2 and 10
What size multiplication table would you like?   (2 - 10): 15
Invalid entry - Enter a number between 2 and 10
What size multiplication table would you like?   (2 - 10): 10
--- Multiplication Table ( 10 x 10 ) ---
       1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |   1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10 
2  |   2      4      6      8     10     12     14     16     18     20 
3  |   3      6      9     12     15     18     21     24     27     30 
4  |   4      8     12     16     20     24     28     32     36     40 
5  |   5     10     15     20     25     30     35     40     45     50 
6  |   6     12     18     24     30     36     42     48     54     60 
7  |   7     14     21     28     35     42     49     56     63     70 
8  |   8     16     24     32     40     48     56     64     72     80 
9  |   9     18     27     36     45     54     63     72     81     90 
10 |  10     20     30     40     50     60     70     80     90    100
```

This is what I have so far:

```
number = float(input("What size multiplication would you like? (2-10): "))
if number > 2 and number <= 10:                  
    print ("\t\t\t---Multiplication Tables---\n")           
for x in range(1,11):              
    print(x, end="\t")
print()
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")

for y in range(1, 11):
    for z in range(1,11):
        print(y * z, end="\t")        
    print ("\n")

else:
    print("Invalid entry - Enter a number between 2 and 10")
```

Comment: You may want to look into while loops instead of if-else

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. A couple of changes to your code that I would recommend:

First, rather than if...else on checking the user input, I'd go with that nested in a while loop:

```
while True:
    number = int(input("What size multiplication would you like? (2-10): "))
    if (number < 2 or number > 10):
        print("Invalid entry - Enter a number between 2 and 10")
    else:
        break
```

I'd also stick to int for the input - do need for floats, since you're working with whole number multiplication.

Second, set the output to scale according to the "number" value from the user:

```
for x in range(1,number + 1):              
    print(x, end="\t")
print()
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")

for y in range(1, 11):
    for z in range(1,number + 1):
        print(y * z, end="\t")        
    print ("\n")
```

This will give a vertical output of the multiplication tables (number * everything from 1 to 10).

To include the multiplying number at the beginning of the row with a divider, you can use:

```
for y in range(1, 11):
    print(str(y).rjust(2), ' |', end = '\t')
    # rest of code ...
```

Note the use of .rjust(2) to right justify the strings. You can throw the .rjust on the end of any string to help format the table.